# How can I get the selected category id after 1st page in pagination?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

```
<?php
include "includes/connection.php";

        //$id=$_REQUEST['category'];
        //$catid=mysql_escape_string($id);

$catid = isset($_GET['category']) ? (int)$_GET['category'] : 0;

$recordsPerPage =4;
# 0
// //default startup page
$pageNum = 1;

if(isset($_GET['p']))
{
$pageNum = $_GET['p'];
settype($pageNum, 'integer');
}
$offset = ($pageNum - 1) * $recordsPerPage;
//set the number of columns
$columns = 1;


//set the number of columns
$columns = 1;

$query = "SELECT temp_id, temp_img, temp_header, temp_resize, temp_small, temp_name, temp_type, cat_id, col_id, artist_id FROM `templates` where   cat_id = '{$catid}' ORDER BY `temp_id` DESC LIMIT $offset, $recordsPerPage";
$result = mysql_query($query);
//we add this line because we need to know the number of rows
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "<div>";
//changed this to a for loop so we can use the number of rows
for($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
if($i % $columns == 0) {
//if there is no remainder, we want to start a new row
echo "<div class='template'>";
}
echo ...........my data(s).
if(($i % $columns) == ($columns - 1) || ($i + 1) == $num_rows) {
echo "</div>";
}
}
}
echo "</div>";
//}
?>  


    <div class="pagination">
    <?
    $query = "SELECT COUNT( temp_id ) AS  `temp_date` FROM `templates` where  cat_id ='{$catid}'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Mysql Err. 2');
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$numrows = $row['temp_date'];
//$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

$maxPage = ceil($numrows/$recordsPerPage);

$nav = '';

for($page = 1; $page <= $maxPage; $page++)
{ if ($page == $pageNum)
{
$nav .= "<span class=\"pegination-selected\">$page</span>";
}
else
{
$nav .= "<aa class=\"pegination\" hreeef=\"javascript:htmlData('$self','p=$page')\">$page</a>";
}
}
if ($pageNum > 1)
{

$page = $pageNum - 1;
$prev = "<aa class=\"pagination\" hreeef=\"javascript:htmlData('$self','p=$page')\"><strong><imgee src=\"images/previous.gif\" alt=\"previous\" width=\"5\" height=\"10\" border=\"0\"/></strong></a>";

$first = "<aa class=\"pagination\" hreeef=\"javascript:htmlData('$self','p=1')\"><strong><imgee src=\"images/previous1.gif\" alt=\"first\" width=\"7\" height=\"10\" border=\"0\" /></strong></a>";
}
else
{
$prev = '<strong> </strong>';
$first = '<strong> </strong>';
}
if ($pageNum < $maxPage)
{
$page = $pageNum + 1;
$next = "<aa  hreeef=\"javascript:htmlData('$self','p=$page')\"> <strong> <imgee src=\"images/next.gif\" alt=\"next\ width=\"5\" height=\"10\" border=\"0\" /></strong></a>";
$last = "<a class=\"pagination\" hreeef=\"javascript:htmlData('$self','p=$maxPage')\"> <strong> <imgee src=\"images/next1.gif\" alt=\"next\" border=\"0\" width=\"7\" height=\"10\" /></strong></a>";
}

else
{
$next = '<strong> </strong>';
$last = '<strong> </strong>';
}
echo "<div class=\"pagination\"> $first $prev <span class=\"pagination-selected\">$nav </span> $next $last </div>";

?>              

Here my ajax code:

function GetXmlHttpObject(handler)
{
var objXMLHttp=null
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
objXMLHttp=new XMLHttpRequest()
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
objXMLHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
}
return objXMLHttp
}

function stateChanged()
{
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
{
document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText
}
else
{
//alert(xmlHttp.status);
}
}

function htmlData(url, qStr)
{
if (url.length==0)
{
document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML="";
return;
}
xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject()
if (xmlHttp==null)
{
alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
return;
}

url=url+"?"+qStr;
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true) ;
xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

How can I get the selected category id after 1st page in pagination?

Answer (score 0):

Do you pass though `category` in the request?  You haven't given us that information (what is the value of `qstr` in the javascript?), but I'd guess not.

You're also passing it straight into an SQL query, which leaves you open to injection.
You should use [`mysql_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_escape_string) to fix that.

Comment: I hv do this with mysql_escape_string(), but not working. 2nd pages goes blank.
I hv unable to pass query string as a category in the javascript,Because i m poor in js programing.

Answer (score 0):

- Post it with the AJAX call and return it
- Store it in a local JS variable
- Add it to the URL
- ...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be aware that `$_GET['p']` gets the value of the 'p' parameter passed in the querystring. Well `$_REQUEST['category']` is doing the same thing. (Technically [`$_REQUEST`](http://php.oregonstate.edu/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) checked everything in `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE`).

So if you haven't set the 'category' in the querystring then it wont contain anything in your code.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should add ?**category=XXX**&sid=RAND... to your url
2. Better use `$category = isset($_GET['category']) ? (int)$_GET['category'] : 0;`

Comment: I hv do with yr code ,but no any changes found.I hv updated full code.Plz see again my code.And send the response to me.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
include ('database connection file ');

?>
 **and this is my index.php**
<?php

if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
 $page=$_GET['page'];
 $offset=$limit * ($page - 1);
    
    
}
else{
 $page=1;
 $offset=0;
 
}

if($page==0 || $page > $page_rec){
 header('location:index.php?page=1');
}


?>

<body>
 <div>
<div class="headingSec">     <h1 align="center">Welcome Admin<a href="adminlogout.php">Logout</a></h1>
        <p align="center">Manage your student database here.</p></div>
        <table  class="trBgColr">
    <thead class="bgColorSec">
                 <th>Registration Id</th>
                 <th>Image</th>
                    <th>Signature</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Father's Name</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Registration Category</th>
                    <th>Phone Number</th>
                    <th>Mobile Number</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>
                </thead>
        <?php
        //$getstudentdetails = "select * from student_details";
 
 $result=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `student_details` LIMIT $offset,$limit");
 
         

    /* fetch associative array */
 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)) {
  
  ?>
   
    <tr>
                 <td><?php echo $row["registration_number"]; ?>
                    <td><?php echo $row["Name"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["Father_Name"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["City"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["Registration_Category"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["Phone_Number"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["Mobile_Number"]; ?></td>
                    <?php if($row['payment_status']==1)
     {?>
      <td><?php echo "Sucsess"; ?></td>
                        <?php
     }
                    else{
      ?>
                        <td><?php echo "Failed"; ?></td>
                        <?php
     }?>
                    <?php
                    }   
                                                                                          
     $pre=$page - 1;
     $next=$page + 1;
   
 ?>
    </tr>
  
 </table>
   
    </div>

<br />
<br />


    <div class="pagination">
  
    <?php
for($i=1;$i<=$page_rec;$i++){
 
 continue;
 ?>
  <a href="?page=<?php echo $i?>"><?php  $i;?> </a>
  <?php } ?>

<a href="?page=<?php echo $pre ;?>">Previous&laquo;</a>

<a href="?page=<?php echo $next ;?>">Next&raquo;</a>
```

Comment: Please describe your solution and do not just give the code.